# How do I reinstall/reset the AMD video driver from CLI in Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: drivers, xorg, 19.10, amd-graphics, gpu-driver

I have an Ubuntu 19.10 on a desktop with an APU AMD Ryzen 5 2400G, which has an integrated Radeon RX Vega 11 Graphic card.

Everything has always worked perfectly until today, when out of the blue it started giving me a black screen during the boot sequence, just before the login screen.

Through GRUB I've entered the root shell in recovery mode, examined some logs in `/var/log`, tried running `startx`, and found that the problem seems to be related to the graphic card configuration:

```
(EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
...
(EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory

(EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
```

I've found a lot of Q&A about this, but many of them are very old (older than five years), and almost everyone were about nVidia drivers, not AMD ones, so I've decided not to play the mad scientist with them.

I've upgraded the system and reinstalled a lot of `xserver-xorg` stuff, but nothing changed

**What should I do to reset my AMD video driver configuration?**

I've never installed any brand specific driver, and I'd be perfectly fine with reinstalling the Ubuntu default ones

Answer (score 0):

https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-rad-lin-19-10-unified and https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ explain the installation process for https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-rx-vega-series/radeon-rx-vega-series/radeon-rx-vega-56

Don't use the Pro drivers; although you download the package which has them, you will instead install the PAL variant (since you have the Vega 11) of the Open-GL drivers by running the **./amdgpu-install** script after downloading and extracting the driver archive file as per https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-script.html .

Comment: Thank you. Where is the *non* Pro driver?

Comment: Also, I just want to clear that I've never installed them and I'd be happy with the default, generic ones

Comment: I've edited the question with more details

Comment: Click on the [Download] button under Ubuntu at https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-rx-vega-series/radeon-rx-vega-series/radeon-rx-vega-56

Comment: That's what I was doing yesterday, but I've stopped when looking at the URL, I've seen those ***are*** the Pro drivers, that you expressly advised against installing it: *drivers.amd.com/drivers/linux/19.50/amdgpu-**`pro`**-19.50-967956-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz*

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1022511)

Comment: @Simon Sudler Thx for the reminder. Answer expanded with detail.